# ReactJS set display='inline' onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to set display property of a child element to inline, when there is a mouseOver or mouseEnter event in this React component.

I can see that the state is being set, but it does not change for the display property.

```
export class EditablePageTitle extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showEditIcon: 'none'
  };

  showEditIcon() {
    console.log('showEditIcon 1 ', this.state.showEditIcon);
    this.setState({ showEditIcon: 'inline' });
    console.log('showEditIcon 2 ', this.state.showEditIcon);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexColumn
        style={{
          alignItems: 'baseline',
          paddingBottom: s[3]
        }}
      >
        <div id="page-title" onMouseEnter={() => this.showEditIcon()}>
          <Input
            {...this.props}
            type={this.props.type || 'text'}
            defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
            disabled="disabled"
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
          />
          <i
            className="fa fa-pencil-alt"
            style={{
              paddingRight: s[3],
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              fontSize: s[3],
              display: this.state.showEditIcon
            }}
          />
          {console.log('this.state.showEditIcon ', this.state.showEditIcon)}
        </div>
        <Label>{this.props.label}</Label>
      </FlexColumn>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try <div id="page-title" onMouseEnter={this.showEditIcon}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a conflict with how Font Awesome and React handle rendering.

> If you are using React we recommend the react-fontawesome package or Web Fonts with CSS.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

However, you may just want to try wrapping your icon with a `span` and apply the `display` property there.

```
<span style={{ display: this.state.showEditIcon }}>
    <i className="fa fa-pencil-alt"
        style={{
            paddingRight: s[3],
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            fontSize: s[3]
        }}
    />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just decided to wrap it in a span, and I'll revisit later and think about installing the other stuff

Answer (score 2):

Call the `showEditIcon` method like the following and also you should bind `this`:

```
export class EditablePageTitle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showEditIcon: 'none'
    };

    this.showEditIcon = this.showEditIcon.bind(this);
  }

    showEditIcon() {
        console.log('showEditIcon 1 ', this.state.showEditIcon);
        this.setState({ showEditIcon: 'inline' });
        console.log('showEditIcon 2 ', this.state.showEditIcon);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexColumn
      style={{
        alignItems: 'baseline',
        paddingBottom: s[3]
      }}
      >
      <div id="page-title" onMouseEnter={this.showEditIcon}>
        <Input
        {...this.props}
        type={this.props.type || 'text'}
        defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
        disabled="disabled"
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        />
        <i
        className="fa fa-pencil-alt"
        style={{
          paddingRight: s[3],
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          fontSize: s[3],
          display: this.state.showEditIcon
        }}
        />
        {console.log('this.state.showEditIcon ', this.state.showEditIcon)}
      </div>
      <Label>{this.props.label}</Label>
      </FlexColumn>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not seeing the icon's display property set to inline

Comment: @ss_matches your error must be elsewhere then. Without additional context it's hard to determine. I tried to recreate your code as best as possible here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r4yl71r44 and it works as expected (also: I opted to use an arrow function instead of `bind()`)